# Returning multiple values in single column from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am joining different tables, and I wanted it to return a concatinated value. As a basic example, let me use the table `.people` and `.contacts`. What I wanted to happen is to query directyly(if possible) to return the all result of `.people` with the corresponding values from `.contacts`

To give you a detail,  this is the **structure of `.people`**

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   naaa | 
|  2 |   hey  | 
+----+--------+
```

and this is the **`.contacts`**

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | per_id |  num   | 
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |   1234 | 
|  2 |      1 |   3456 |  
|  3 |      1 |   8901 | 
|  4 |      2 |   1111 | 
+----+--------+--------+
```

I want it to somehow return

```
+----+--------+--------------------+
| id |  name  |        num         |
+----+--------+--------------------+
|  1 |  naaa  |   1234,3456,8901   |
|  2 |   hey  |       1111         |
+----+--------+--------------------+
```

is that doable with MySQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `GROUP_CONCAT':

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(num  SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM people as p
INNER JOIN contacts as c on p.id = c.per_id 
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(num  SEPARATOR ', ') as num
FROM people as p
INNER JOIN contacts as c on p.id = c.per_id 
GROUP BY p.id
```